# View pages of an ASP.NET MVC application in an Angular SPA

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to include parts of an ASP.NET MVC application into an Angular SPA. The goal is to build a frame with Angular that shows certain pages of a business application build in ASP.NET MVC.

What is the best appraoch to achieve this? I tried to include pages of the ASP.NET MCV pages with

```
* <object type="text/html" data=...>
* <iframe src=...>
```

Both solution didn't work. One of the problems is that the ASP.NET MCV pages produce a dynamic link. The url is something like http://mvcapp/page.axd?ContextID=X which results in http response that contains a Location redirect to something like http://mvcapp/page.axd?RuntimeFormID=87faf21a-ab69-411d-bb4d-e012dfd24539.

On checking the Network area in the debugging tools of Chrome, i can see that both approaches creating a tons of get requests on different dynamic created urls and all respond with Status Code "302 Found".

Do you have any ideas how to get this running?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I remember the last time making integration between ASP.NET form with an Angular app, we used a simple solution which allows Angular App to open a popup of ASP.NET forms and use some kind of window event source (window.onmessage/window.parent.postMessage).

Two applications work independently and Angular app only needs to get the result from the ASP.NET pages.